# Hadoop replication factor is 3.How much data is stored ?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Industry standard replication factor for Hadoop is 3. So does this mean that if there is a data of 100 GB then In HDFS it will be stored as 300 GB ?

Comment: Keep in mind that during an operation on that data, additional, temporary files will be created as well

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

There are other factors such as block size (128MB by default) which might introduce fragmentation when files are very small or are slightly bigger than the block size but in general 100GB in HDFS equals 300GB on disk.